# How can I make a box of content in html?

Tags: html, positioning

I'm trying to learn html and I need to be able to section things into the spot they are meant to be in
So like each thing will have a picture and some text

I need to make a blue box and inside it I need a image and text
And next to it, the same thing.
Basically if I had a way to create a new   inside the real one? I guess. Im not sure.
This is what I tried, and its pretty much what I want but I need the box to be solid, and maybe if someone could help me make the image and text centered on the horizontal axis that could also help.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            MaGa V1
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .img_div {float: left; border: 1px solid white;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body  bgcolor="#000000">
        <div class="img_div" style="margin-right: 32px">
            <img src="./../images/Shadows over Innistrad/Shadows over Innistrad.png"/>
            <figcaption>
                <a href="./Shadows over Innistrad.html" target="_self">Shadows over Innistrad</a>
            </figcaption>
        </div>
        <div class="img_div" style="margin-right: 32px">
            <img src="./../images/Battle for Zendikar/Battle for Zendikar.png"/>
            <figcaption>
                <a href="./Battle for Zendikar.html" target="_self">Battle for Zendikar</a>
            </figcaption>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```css
body {background-color:black;}
.row{overflow:hidden;} /* Fixes float */
.img_div {float:left;width:45%;text-align:center;padding:10px;background:blue;}
.img_div:not(:nth-child(2)){margin-right:10px;}
.img_div a{color:gold;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="img_div">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/102" />
    <figcaption>
      <a href="./Shadows over Innistrad.html" target="_self">Shadows over Innistrad</a>
    </figcaption>
  </div>
  <div class="img_div">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/102/102" />
    <figcaption>
      <a href="./Battle for Zendikar.html" target="_self">Battle for Zendikar</a>
    </figcaption>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- .row -->
```

---

The entire page might look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Usually there is some stuff in here -- up to you -->
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        body {background-color:black;}
        .row{overflow:hidden;} /* Fixes float */
        .img_div {float:left;width:45%;text-align:center;padding:10px;background:blue;}
        .img_div:not(:nth-child(2)){margin-right:10px;}
        .img_div a{color:gold;}
    </style>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="img_div">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/102" />
        <figcaption>
          <a href="./Shadows over Innistrad.html" target="_self">Shadows over Innistrad</a>
        </figcaption>
      </div>
      <div class="img_div">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/102/102" />
        <figcaption>
          <a href="./Battle for Zendikar.html" target="_self">Battle for Zendikar</a>
        </figcaption>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I suggest you do [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/), and then [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp) *Just run through them quickly*

---

You can only use a percentage for height if the parent container (`.row` in the example above) has a fixed height. The parent container's height can be in px, %, vh, em -- but it cannot be auto.

A couple of ideas to get around that are:
(1) to use `padding` to increase the height as desired, or 
(2) to use `height:30vh`

`vh` is very similar to `%`, but it is measured by screen units (e.g. 30/100 of screen height instead of `30 percent of parent height`) - and does not require the parent element to have a set height. (Note that there is also `vw` for width settings. *These are also useful units for `responsive` settings as using vw/vh you can make sizes exactly proportionate on differently sized screens.*

[**jsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/xhva6cc9/)

Comment: That works perfectly in the run code snippet but I can't seem to figure out how to actually use it >.< I tried replacing my body with it, it had a bunch of text everywhere and showed the cats, and no blue box, and I tried replacing my whole thing with it and it also did not work. I'm sorry, today is like my second day of html >.< [Edit] I figured it out thanks a bunch!

Comment: Place the CSS under the `<body>` tag and **between `<style></style>` tags.**

Comment: Alright one more thing, I tried to change the height of the boxes but its not working img_div {float:left;width:25%;height:40%$;text-align:center;padding:10px;background:blue;}

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote (Or at least, to show my upvote I guess?)

Comment: You need 15 rep to upvote - looks like you have it now. Congrats! It comes quickly, especially when you answer other questions. *Best wishes for your project*